# jQuery .remove() not working, while other inbuilt functions are

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to remove a div from the DOM, but for some reason .remove() isn't working. I assumed it was an incorrect selector, but I can get the html with .html() just fine. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="collectionsHeading" class="filter-toggle-heading ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
  <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
  Collection
  <div class="filter-applied">
    <span class="right">(8)</span>
    Internal
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery/Javascript

```
$('#collections').val(collections);
var selectedCollection = $('#collectionList').children('#'+collections).html();
var headingValue = $('#collectionsHeading').html();
$('#collectionsHeading').find('.filter-applied').remove();
$('#collectionsHeading').html(headingValue+'<div class="filter-applied">'+selectedCollection+'</div>');
```

Other things I have tried are .children() and puttin it all in the first selecter. All cases allow me to pull the .html(), but .remove() never works. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#collectionsHeading .filter-applied').remove();`?

Comment: Yes, and just double checked then, it's beyond weird.

Comment: If you don't run anything else but the line with `.remove()`, does it work then? Are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: looks just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Er2T/1/

Comment: Yes, when I run it by itself it works, but no errors in the console. So I guess my issue is part of the rest of the jQuery, but its confusing to me that I would be able to pull the html, but not manipulate the div in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remove works just fine, it's just that it makes no difference on the final result.

Here you are getting the HTML code inside the heading:

```
var headingValue = $('#collectionsHeading').html();
```

Here you remove an element from inside the heading:

```
$('#collectionsHeading').find('.filter-applied').remove();
```

Here you remove everything inside the heading, and puts in everything that was there before you removed that element, plus another element:

```
$('#collectionsHeading').html(headingValue+'<div class="filter-applied">'+selectedCollection+'</div>');
```

So, removing the element has no effect, as you get the HTML code for it before removing it, and then use that HTML code to put all the original elements back.

I think that what you are after is removing the element, and then add a new version of it. Don't get the HTML code and put it back, just use `remove` and `append` to remove and add elements:

```
$('#collectionsHeading').find('.filter-applied').remove();
$('#collectionsHeading').append('<div class="filter-applied">'+selectedCollection+'</div>');
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you so much. Today has not been my day, thank you for explaining it so kindly, even though it was obviously my mushy brain that was the issue. Thank god it's friday!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine

```
$('#collectionsHeading').find('.filter-applied').remove();
```

Here is a fiddle... if you comment out the one line and hit play the object isn't removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/bY42X/

Maybe an issue with the version of jQuery you're using or is it possibly firing before the dom is ready?